# Push Notification Action Button Not Displaying - Background and Kill State - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-push-notification

I have implemented firebase push notifications using Firebase and [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) package.

Currently, I have implemented action buttons according to the click_action of each push notification. Once the app is in the foreground it works and once the app is killed state or background action buttons are not displaying.

My FCM helper file

```
class FCMServiceHelper {
  register = (onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification) => {
    this.checkPermission(onRegister);
    this.createNotificationListeners(
      onRegister,
      onNotification,
      onOpenNotification,
    );
  };

  registerAppWithFCM = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
      await messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    }
  };

  checkPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .hasPermission()
      .then((enabled) => {
        if (enabled) {
          // User has permissions
          this.deleteToken()
          this.getToken(onRegister);
        } else {
          // User doesn't have permission
          this.requestPermission(onRegister);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Permission rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  getToken = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .getToken(undefined,'*')
      .then((fcmToken) => {
        if (fcmToken) {
          onRegister(fcmToken);
        } else {
          console.log('[FCMService] User does not have a device token');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] getToken rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  requestPermission = (onRegister) => {
    messaging()
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        this.deleteToken()
        this.getToken(onRegister);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Request Permission rejected ', error);
      });
  };

  deleteToken = () => {
    console.log('[FCMService] deleteToken ');
    messaging()
      .deleteToken(undefined,'*')
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Delete token error ', error);
      });
  };

  unregisterDeviceFromNotifications = () => {
    console.log('[FCMService] unreg ');
    messaging()
      .unregisterDeviceForRemoteMessages()
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('[FCMService] Unreg device ', error);
      });
  };

  createNotificationListeners = (
    onRegister,
    onNotification,
    onOpenNotification,
  ) => {
    // When the application is running, but in the background
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        '[FCMService] onNotificationOpenedApp Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage,
      );
      if (remoteMessage) {
        let notification = null;
        let data = remoteMessage.data;
        let openFromKilling = {"checked" : true}
        notification = remoteMessage.notification;
        notification.data = data;
        notification.checking = openFromKilling;
        onOpenNotification(notification);
      }
    });

    // When the application is opened from a quit state.
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then((remoteMessage) => {
        console.log(
          '[FCMService] getInitialNotification Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage,
        );

        if (remoteMessage) {
          let notification = null;
          let data = remoteMessage.data;
          let openFromKilling = {"checked" : true}
          notification = remoteMessage.notification;
          notification.data = data;
          notification.checking = openFromKilling;
          onOpenNotification(notification);
        }
      });

    // Foreground state messages
    this.messageListener = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        '[FCMService] A new FCM message arrived! foreground',
        remoteMessage,
      );
      if (remoteMessage) {
        let notification = null;
        let data = remoteMessage.data;

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          notification = remoteMessage.notification;
        } else {
          notification = remoteMessage.notification;
        }
        notification.data = data;
        onNotification(notification);
        // onOpenNotification(remoteMessage.data);
      }
    });
    // Triggered when have new token
    // messaging().onTokenRefresh((fcmToken) => {
    //   alert('REFRESH TOKEN');
    //   console.log('[FCMService] New token refresh: ', fcmToken);
    //   onRegister(fcmToken);
    // });
  };

  unRegister = () => {
    // if(this.messageListener){
      this.messageListener();
    // }
  };
}
```

My notification Handler file

```
fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotificaion , onAction);
localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotificaion,onAction);

function onRegister(token) {
  saveFCMToken(token);
}

if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
  localNotificationService.createChannelAndroid('wapp');
}

function onNotification(notify) {
  var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  let actionData = [];

  if(Platform.OS == 'android'){
    if(notify.data.click_action == 'alert_dashboard'){
      actionData = ["Update contact number"]
    }else if(notify.data.click_action == 'account_edit'){
      actionData = ["Update Email"]
    }
  }

  const options = {
    soundName: 'default',
    playSound: true,
  };
  localNotificationService.showNotification(
    RandomNumber,
    notify.title,
    Platform.OS == 'android' ? notify.body : notify.body,
    notify,
    options,
    'wapp',
    actionData
  );
}
function onAction(notification) {
  console.log ('Notification action received:');
  console.log(notification.action);
  console.log(notification);
}
```

Notification Helper File

```
class NotificationHelper {
  configure = (onOpenNotification) => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('[NotificationManager] onRegister token:', token.token);
      },

      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('[NotificationManager] onNotification:', notification);

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          if (notification.data.openedInForeground) {
            notification.userInteraction = true;
          }
        }

        if (notification.userInteraction) {
          onOpenNotification(notification);
        } else {
          onNotification(notification);
        }

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          notification.userInteraction = true;
        }

        // Only call callback if not from foreground
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          if (!notification.data.openedInForeground) {
            notification.finish('backgroundFetchResultNoData');
          }
        } else {
          notification.finish('backgroundFetchResultNoData');
        }
      },
      onAction: function (notification) {
        // alert(notification)
        console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
        // notification.userInteraction = true;
        // PushNotification.invokeApp(notification);
      },
    });
  };

  unregister = () => {
    PushNotification.unregister();
  };

  createChannelAndroid = (channel) => {
    PushNotification.createChannel(
      {
        channelId: channel, // (required)
        channelName: 'My channel', // (required)
        channelDescription: 'A channel to categorise your notifications', // (optional) default: undefined.
        playSound: false, // (optional) default: true
        soundName: 'default', // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
        importance: 4, // (optional) default: 4. Int value of the Android notification importance
        vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
      },
      (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`), // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
    );
  };

  showNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}, channel , testData) => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      ...this.buildAndroidNotification(
        id,
        title,
        message,
        data,
        options,
        channel,
        testData
      ),
      /* iOS and Android properties */
      ...this.buildIOSNotification(id, title, message, data, options),
      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: title || '',
      message: message || '',
      playSound: options.playSound || true,
      soundName: options.soundName || 'default',
      userInteraction: true, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
    });
  };

  buildAndroidNotification = (
    id,
    title,
    message,
    data = {},
    options = {},
    channel,
    testData
  ) => {
    console.log('TEST DATA -> ',data)
    return {
      showWhen: true,  // This is probably not needed, since default value is TRUE.
      when: new Date().getTime(),
      group: "wapp",
      groupSummary: true,
      channelId: channel,
      id: id,
      autoCancel: true,
      largeIcon: options.largeIcon || 'ic_launcher',
      smallIcon: options.smallIcon || 'ic_launcher',
      bigText: message || '',
      subText: title || '',
      vibrate: options.vibrate || true,
      vibration: options.vibration || 300,
      priority: options.priority || 'high',
      importance: options.importance || 'high', // (optional) set notification importance, default: high,
      data: data,
      actions:testData,
      // invokeApp:false,
    };
  };

  buildIOSNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) => {
    return {
      alertAction: options.alertAction || 'view',
      alertBody: message || '',
      category: options.category || '',
      userInfo: {
        id: id,
        item: data,
      },
    };
  };

  cancelAllLocalNotifications = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      PushNotificationIOS.removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
    } else {
      PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
    }
  };

  removeDeliveredNotificationByID = (notificationId) => {
    console.log(
      '[LocalNotificationService] removeDeliveredNotificationByID: ',
      notificationId,
    );
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: `${notificationId}`});
  };
}
```

My app index.js file

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AppRegistry, LogBox, YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/Entrypoint';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { backgroundGeo, checkLocationLogics } from './app/helpers/backgroundLocationTracking';
import env from 'react-native-config';

enableScreens();

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HeadlessCheck);
```

Comment: Hey did you manage to complete this? Could you please share a gist or something of above mentioned files. I need to handle similar problem

Comment: @VinayN unfortunately not found any solution

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the showNotification method inside setBackgroundMessageHandler , this gets called when the app is not in foreground or killed state

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  const options = {
      soundName: 'default',
      playSound: true,
    };
    const {title, body, data} = remoteMessage;
    localNotificationService.showNotification(
      title,
      body,
      data,
      options,
  }
});
```